# Why do file copy operations in Linux get slower over time?

Tags: linux, performance, file-transfer, xfce

I have 12 ~200 MB files. Copying one of them to another drive takes 20 seconds. When I try to copy all of them at once, it first says it's going to take 5 minutes, then it keeps slowing down into the hours and days.

I'm copying the files through Thunar in XFCE, but I remember having similar problems using the command line. Why does this occur and what can I do to remedy it, other than just copying the files one by one?

Comment: Have you checked the drive for errors?  Are these files in sub-folders?

Comment: @tubaguy50035 The files are not in sub-folders. That being said, it's likely that the source drive may have errors. I'll check.

Comment: @CodeGnome I did a basic cp -v sourcedir/* destdir.

Answer (score 48):

This is a known issue with the Linux kernel itself that has been known for ages, no one was tackled the issue yet.

there is currently no fix or known work-around, aside from using Windows which increases in speed and then normalizes. I find this bug to be a very high-priority issue, but the programmers do not feel the same way. It is this bug alone that is starting to drive me away from Linux.

Refs:

- [Bug 12309 - Large I/O operations result in poor interactive performance and high iowait times](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12309)
- [USB file transfer causes system freezes; ops take hours instead of minutes](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/500069)

Comment: Citation Required! It might help work our an answer if you could give some documentation that points to this bug

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/500069

Comment: and here, which can be found as a link in the original citation. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12309

Comment: You drive away from Linux just for this reason???

Comment: I can understand your point. I'm trying to copy 50gb data from my old ssd to my new one via usb 3.0. It's a pain in the ass, really.

Comment: @Kyrol this is a very big reason!

Comment: Has any solution been figured out for this? It's 2019 and I'm still having the issue.

Comment: @Everyone - While the problem discussed above is important and thus seems to justify the high votes of the answer, the problem in the question (not in the title) has nothing to do with it, but it is obviously triggered by the **copying at once of 12 files** 200MB each.

Comment: 2022 and this is still an issue. Any file transfer slows down over time until it reaches 25kbps which is a huge reason to start development with windows.

Answer (score 10):

You should try *rsync* to monitor your transfer speed. For example:

```
rsync -PSauv sourcedir/* destdir/
```

If you actually see a drop in transfer speed, as opposed to files that are just big, then you need to look at a few other things.

1. If your disk is I/O-bound, you will have problems. You often see this
   when writing heavily to a flash drive or an external USB device.
2. Test both your disks with `hdparm -Tt <device>` to see if one is
   dramatically slower than it should be, or dramatically slower than
   the other device which can lead to I/O issues.
3. Check your *dmesg* output and your SMART status to make sure you
   don't have any obvious disk errors. You might also consider
   `badblocks -n` if you suspect disk errors on a non-SMART drive.

There are lots of reasons why a disk can thrash or perform sub-optimally, but until you can measure the problem, you won't know what the problem is. :)

Answer (score 3):

Remember that also the file copy process is somehow cached by Linux. If you take a single file (even if a 200MB one) and start copying it to another place, Linux caches, with great probability, the whole file in memory and writes it in its new location. Then, if you choose to copy that file again and with it a bunch of other files, then the first file is already cached and then probably skips the whole "read part", while the others are first read from and then written to their sources/destinations. This feature can even lead to infinite transfer speeds and similar oddities, so don't trust any measurement that could be invalidated by previous chaching mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to copy a 4 GB file to a fat32 usb stick.

after 1 GB has been copied, copy speed reduced from c. 20 MB/s to c. 0.5 MB/s.

I formatted the stick to ext4 but it didn't help.

Then I formatted the stick to NTFS as advised [here](https://superuser.com/a/970466/501858), and had a dramatic improvement in speed:

```
$ rsync --progress movie.mkv /run/media/user/09D8E089029531DD/
movie.mkv
  3,759,209,408 100%    7.90MB/s    0:08:46 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
```

PS: this doesn't answer the question but hopefully may solve the problem with speed.

Answer (score 0):

The "hours and days" problem is related to having *12 copying processes simultaneously*, which stresses the CPU, hence the odd estimated time. The time of copying 12x200=2400MB is surely reasonable, no matter what ETA is displayed in Thunar.

For more info during copying, [some file managers provide more info](https://askubuntu.com/a/1298136/925128) than Thunar.

Answer (score -3):

Burn a copy of [SliTaz](http://www.slitaz.org/en/get/) onto a CD/USB.

It is designed for use on really ancient machines and runs really fast since it's in RAM. You don't need to do an install, just run it live. If you have a USB mounted, you will be able to see it, and then copy what you need to your computer. The transfer rates I have found to be stable and fast.